# about nancyfx use dotliquid viewengine

Tags: nancy, dotliquid

I have referenced `Nancy.Viewengines.DotLiquid` and `DotLiquid` but there is a bug in NancyFx response:

> Nancy.RequestExecutionException: Oh noes! ---> Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewNotFoundException: Unable to locate view 'index'
>   Currently available view engine extensions: sshtml,html,htm
>   Locations inspected: views/Index/index-zh-CN,views/Index/index,Index/index-zh-CN,Index/index,views/index-zh-CN,views/index,index-zh-CN,index

`this.ViewEngines.ToList()` only has `Nancy.ViewEngines.SuperSimpleViewEngine.SuperSimpleViewEngineWrapper`.

How can I set the dotliquid engine for nancy?

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking. Apart from bad English, technical stuff needs to be elaborated as well.

Comment: As stated in the [wiki](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/View-engines): "By adding a reference to them from your project Nancy will automatically be able to render views using their supported file extensions". Does your views have a `.liquid` extension?